# Pulling email from remote server via Exchange

Tags: windows, exchange

I'm tasked with rebuilding the entire IT setup in a small office. Because of my apprenticeship in the field I have enough experience to set up Windows Server, but I've never worked with Exchange.
My current approach is to configure everything in a virtual environment and then deploy it on metal when everything works.

Now this office had a bunch of IT-people come and go over the years and this is why I'm rebuilding from scratch. None of those people are available to talk to, mostly because they are out of business.

Especially the email setup is really weird and this is the part I'm struggeling to configure.

Right now they have an Exchange Server running that would pull emails in from an external server. This external server is hosted by their website service and included in their package. I've been told using just the exchange server is not an option. Currently, all emails sent to the business email will be fetched by the Exchange Server and delivered to the domain mailboxes. Email sent via domain accounts would be relayed via smarthost.

Just to make it a bit more clear:

- Client A sends message to human@business.com
- Message is received and stored by business.com server
- In-house Exchange Server somehow checks business.com mailboxes and relays emails to domain mailboxes (e.g. human@business.local)

This might just be me failing to express this in a google search query, but I've got no idea how to set this up.

They are currently running Windows SBS 2011 and Exchange 2010. I'm building the system on Windows Server 2016 Standard and Exchange 2016. The office has no static IP address.

Comment: `I've been told using just the exchange server is not an option` - Told this by whom? Why? The business is better served by not trying to host email themselves as it's obvious that none of you posses the requisite skills, no offense. Why not speak to the "powers that be" about moving email to Office 365/Exchange Online?

Comment: Agree with previous comment. A “small office” should not be running an exchange server. Office 365 is cheap and easy and without a doubt better than any hosting provider they are using.  They are in this position because they are being given bad advice. Fix the problem properly and tell them they shouldn’t be doing silly things like fetching email from a web host.

Answer (score 1):

Exchange Server doesn't have built-in support for fetching mail from external servers via POP3 or IMAP. There are some third party tools for that, though.

As you are building your setup from scratch, I wouldn't take that path. That kind of setup would need to know list of passwords for every external mailbox. It's much easier and more manageable to make the external server forward all mail to your local Exchange.

Comment: In the case of Small Business Server 2011 there is indeed a POP3 connector that is used for this very purpose.

Comment: Good to know. Haven't been working with SBS for years.